# Swiper issue after append slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, swiper.js

i work on a cordova and jquery project.
I use **Swiper**  by idangero for the slides.

my issue appears when i append new slides and try to display them.

*Jquery code:*

```
if(row.pictures != ''){
    var num_slide = mySwiper.slides.length;
    console.log("[slidecontent ] "+slidecontent);
    mySwiper.appendSlide([slidecontent]);
    for (var i = 0; i < num_slide; i++) {
        mySwiper.removeSlide(0);
    }
    mySwiper.update();
}
```

*The **slidecontent** console log display that:*

```
[slidecontent ] '<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="..."></div>',
'<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="..."></div>',
'<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="..."></div>'
```

But it displays that:
*HTML code*

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0ms; -webkit-transition: 0ms;">
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-active" data-swiper-slide-index="0">
            <img src="..."></div>
            '',
            '',
            '<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" data-swiper-slide-index="0"><img src="..."></div>'
            <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" data-swiper-slide-index="0">
            <img src="..."></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue comes from the update() method, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I met this one before, what I did was destroying the old one and initialise the updated swiper.