# why swiper slider doesn't play after using *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, swiper.js

I'm using angular 7 for my project and I need to make a highligth section using [swiper slider by idangero](https://idangero.us/swiper/) but i got a problem when using `*ngFor` i can render the data correctly but the slider won't play except i use `ctr + shift + i` or console after open it. and got stuck only for the last data I input. what i want to achieve is a slider that render data like [this page](http://www.themezaa.com/html/pofo/home-classic-digital-agency.html).

I already read this topic but still not solve my problem:

[Swiper issue after append slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190136/swiper-issue-after-append-slides)

[Swiper slider not working unless page is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770106/swiper-slider-not-working-unless-page-is-resized)

this is my **html** code:

```
<!-- start slider section -->
<section class="no-padding main-slider height-100 mobile-height wow fadeIn ">
  <div class="swiper-full-screen swiper-container height-100 width-100 black-move">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

      <!-- start slider item -->
      <div class="swiper-slide cover-background" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x991');" *ngFor="let data of allNews">
        <div class="container position-relative full-screen">
          <div class="col-md-12 slider-typography text-center text-md-left">
            <div class="slider-text-middle-main">
              <div class="slider-text-middle">
                <h1 class="alt-font text-extra-dark-gray font-weight-700 letter-spacing-minus-1 line-height-80 width-55 margin-35px-bottom lg-width-60 md-width-70 lg-line-height-auto sm-width-100 sm-margin-15px-bottom">{{data.title}}</h1>

                <p class="text-extra-dark-gray text-large margin-four-bottom width-40 lg-width-50 md-width-60 sm-width-100 sm-margin-15px-bottom">{{data.summary}}</p>

                <div class="btn-dual">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-transparent-dark-gray btn-rounded btn-small margin-20px-lr sm-margin-5px-top">Selengkapnya</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end slider item -->

    </div>
    <!-- start slider pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-full-screen-pagination"></div>
    <!-- end slider pagination -->
  </div>
</section>
<!-- end slider section -->
```

for the **json:**

```
[{
    "_id": "5ceac4c07b8ae43702a9ed75",
    "title": "test 1",
    "summary": "Very Test 1",
    "imageCover": "5ceac4c07b8ae43702a9ed76 Cover.jpg"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ceaa000e5f34b3a55b456ed",
    "title": "Test 2",
    "summary": "Very Test 2",
    "imageCover": "5ceaa000e5f34b3a55b486ed Cover.jpg"
  }
],
```

can someone help me to solve this? the data itself already render but the swiper doesn't autoplay and i can't manually it

Answer (score 1):

Never used swipper, but according to their [getting started](https://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/) page, you need to "jump start" it.

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';

var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { /* ... */ });
```

since this looks like it depends on the DOM to work, i'd make sure to run it after the view fully loaded.

so something like

```
 import Swiper from 'swiper';

 // ...

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
 }
```

this obviously works as far as I can tell: [demo with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yybpmt)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Angular 11+

[Swiper needs resize to work properly](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/2276#issuecomment-339918354)

or

Try this - add :

```
(swiper)="onSwiper($event)"
```

to your swiper HTML component.

```
<swiper (swiper)="onSwiper($event)"></swiper>
```

And in your `.TS` component, add:

```
onSwiper(swiper) {
  swiper.update();
}
```